no terminaba de sentirme cómoda con alguna
I am reading a Spanish novel and I am stuck at this sentence.

Conseguir compañera de departamento no fue tan sencillo como
imaginé: cuando ellas llegaban a ver el espacio y a hablarme de sus vidas en
la ciudad, no terminaba de sentirme cómoda con alguna.

and the translation of this paragraph is

Getting a roommate was not as easy as I imagined. when they came to
see the space
and talk to me about their lives in the city, I didn't feel comfortable with any of them.

How can the last part "no terminaba de sentirme cómoda con alguna" be translated to "I didn't feel comfortable with any of them." ? I understand the tense, the words, but the whole sentence doesn't make sense to me. Thanks.

Literally this would be "I hadn't finished feeling comfortable with any of them yet." It's a way of conveying that there's some process of feeling not at all comfortable -> feeling comfortable eventually, I suppose, and it's a little more literary.

I think the confusion might stem from the use of "terminaba" here. Without other context you might normally interpret this as "I didn't finish", but the full phrase "no terminaba de" is an idiomatic expression that means something like "I didn't completely" or "I wasn't fully".
So therefore adding that translation back to the rest of the sentence, it would then become "I didn't completely feel comfortable with any of them" or "I wasn't fully comfortable with any of them".

I think that Cory explained the sentence quite well but just to add additional useful sources ...
terminar de + infinitivo is a perífrasis verbal.

Verb periphrases (perífrasis verbales) are verb combinations made up
of an auxiliary verb and a main verb. The main verb always uses a
non-personal form: infinitive, gerundio, or past participle.

Specifically this one belongs to a subcategory

Verb periphrases that express a phase Some verb periphrases refer to
the preparation, the beginning, the end, or the interruption of an
action.

In your case we are talking about the ending (terminar/finish) of an action (feeling comfortable).
Why is the author using this kind of construction? He or she could have used directly the verb sentir (feel) without using a periphrases. That's what you got in your translation. But using the periphrases (terminar de sentir) instead reflects that there is an evaluation process for the candidates with different phases, it starts with a neutral opinion about the candidate but finishes with a negative one after hearing what the candidates have said.
More examples related to different periphrases (doc in English - I took the definitions from it) here.
Detailed and pretty specialised info about this specific type of periphrases  (in Spanish) here.
